# Xcode 7 Swift Chat de Audio em Rede Local

Tags: swift, áudio, redes

Estou desenvolvendo um simples aplicativo em Swift que possa fazer "ligação" na rede local, sem uso de servidor externo, já trabalhei com socket em C++ onde fazia stream de imagens da tela do computador, mas com Swift não por onde começar. Procurei na internet e só achei SDK que usa servidores externos. Grato desde já.

Comment: Não ficou claro o que realmente você quer, está procurando algo pronto ou quer desenvolver do zero?

Comment: Quero desenvolver do zero, queria só umas dicas de por onde começar.